# .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top) effects width and causes page content to shrink

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm creating a full-page vertical scroll like TikTok.

I'm able to do so using the following code:

```
struct ViewA: View {
    let colors: [Color] = [ .red, .green, .blue, .gray ]

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { proxy in
            TabView {
                ForEach(colors, id: \.self) { color in
                    ZStack {
                        color
                        VStack {
                            Text("Hello World")
                        }
                    }
                }
                .rotationEffect(.degrees(-90))
                .frame(
                    width: proxy.size.width,
                    height: proxy.size.height
                )
            }
            .frame(
                width: proxy.size.height,
                height: proxy.size.width
            )
            .rotationEffect(.degrees(90), anchor: .topLeading)
            .offset(x: proxy.size.width)
            .tabViewStyle(
                PageTabViewStyle(indexDisplayMode: .never)
            )
        }
    }
}
```

[image: preview]

However, when I remove the top safe area(make the content fill the entire screen including safe area) using `.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)`, my content shrinks in width a bit.

```
var body: some View {
    GeometryReader { proxy in
        TabView {
            ForEach(colors, id: \.self) { color in
                ZStack {
                    color
                    VStack {
                        Text("Hello World")
                    }
                }
            }
            .rotationEffect(.degrees(-90))
            .frame(
                width: proxy.size.width,
                height: proxy.size.height
            )
        }
        .frame(
            width: proxy.size.height,
            height: proxy.size.width
        )
        .rotationEffect(.degrees(90), anchor: .topLeading)
        .offset(x: proxy.size.width)
        .tabViewStyle(
            PageTabViewStyle(indexDisplayMode: .never)
        )
    }
    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top) <----- This line causes the problem
}
```

[image: preview]

I'm very new to native ios development please help. TIA~!

Comment: Could you tell me the reason you used "rotationEffect, frame and offset" in your code? I see that we still got the same UI if remove them.

Comment: @Bao not sure, I was just following this tutorial to implement vertical page scroll feature. https://blog.prototypr.io/how-to-vertical-paging-in-swiftui-f0e4afa739ba

Comment: You may should add `.navigationBarHidden(true)`